# Using awk/sed/perl i want to remove the self closing tag and its content and add an empty space

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have the following string:

```
<Sub4Topic hi="1d9bhb" cbdshfghfgs(C)(2)(d)"><step stepid=" ajhdjgjgjfhgjhgrhghr" stepid="du" />
```

Here I want the step tag and its content to be removed.
The output should be:

```
<Sub4Topic hi="1d9bhb" cbdshfghfgs(C)(2)(d)">
```

Answer (score 3):

Well for what you have posted you could use

```
| sed -r 's/<step[^>]+>/ /'
```

(`[^>]+` means some characters that are not `>`) but if you need something more flexible then please post more of your input.

Comment: er, thanks for the edits folks... not sure how I managed to type that horribly...

Comment: I always forget that last one....